# iOS6 command execution

Tags: ios, ios6

The code below is executed twice in iOS6 for some reason. I have no problems with lower versions of iOS. If I run the lite version of my app, the output is

```
Lite Version
Lite Version
```

Any idea how I can fix this problem..

Thanks..

```
#ifdef LITE_VERSION
    NSLog(@"Lite Version");
#else
    NSLog(@"Pro Version");

#endif
```

Comment: Word to the wise, iOS 6 is still under NDA. If you are a Apple Dev, might want to post on the Apple Dev forums.

Comment: @tarheel: actually, [SO does not legally respect the NDA](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40889/do-some-of-the-questions-answers-of-stackoverflow-break-sdk-agreements), nor must they.  The OP may post at his own discretion, and we may freely answer.

Comment: @CodaFi still, best to advise people that they could lose their dev account.

Comment: @borrrden: considering how many iOS devs there are, and how many email accounts they may or may not use (let alone openly advertise that they use), combined with variable user names makes enforcement impossible.  Besides, he's asking about a CLANG feature (macros), it's not necessarily NDA material.

Comment: Whatever's causing that to execute twice isn't in the code you posted. What method is it in, and how does the class in which that method is implemented fit into your app?

Comment: it's in the viewdidload method and i am calling it as is.. plus.. like i said it's working in the lower verions of ios..

Comment: if this code is in the viewdidlod method my guess is that the view is loaded twice. the code above has no whatsoever issues with it.

Comment: @CodaFi does a non enforceable contract violation action make that action legal? I know it is up the OP but just as borrrden correctly states, it was mostly a matter of hinting a possible violation and not a letter of cease and desist.

Comment: @Till, this issue is null now.  iOS 6 is out of NDA.

Comment: I think it is kinda pointless but still i felt it was fun to quote it: `Xcode 4.5 GM seed and iOS 6 GM seed are pre-release software and are considered Apple Confidential Information and are subject to the terms of your iOS Developer Program License Agreement. Unauthorized distribution or disclosure of Apple Confidential Information is prohibited.`